# why is git rebase flagging conflicts on new branch specific files

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I have a maddening little git rebase issue going on right now.

The brief summary is that there are conflicts on files where there should not possibly be conflicts. I have read many questions on SO and many articles but nothing I have found seems to address an issue quite like this.

#### What I did

I cloned a remote repository and have been keeping it up to date with git pull --rebase, then rebasing that local master into a local branch:

```
    git pull --rebase (on master)
    git checkout mybranch
    git rebase master mybranch
    <rebases cleanly>
```

which looks something like:

```
    master ----o-o-o-o--------o-o-------------o
                \          \ (pull --rebase)   \(pull --rebase (successful)
    local master ---o-o      o-o-o-o            rebase master to mybranch fails 
                       \            \ (rebase)    
    mybranch           --------A-B   o-A-B-C
```

I was only adding new files and this worked great until up until a few weeks ago when I started to 
get some merge conflicts on files that do not exist on the remote or local master branch.

```
    git pull --rebase (on master branch and successfully)
    git checkout mybranch
    git rebase master mybranch (conflicts in files that do not exist on master)
```

I had never merged anything back to to the local or the remote.

There are basically 4 files out of about 100 that I have added that continually get conflicts and during rebase they want to be merged again and again with the same diff over and over and over.

git version 2.9.3

### Things I have tried (that did not work or help)

1. Confirmed that I never commited anything on the local master branch and that these conflict files do not exist
2. Cloned another copy of the repo and confirmed I have never commited anything and that these conflict files do not exist
3. I did a `"git reset --hard HEAD"` before the rebase, no help.
   removed some local .gitignore files that were not tracked to try to isolate any behavior that may be happening and not consistent between branches.
4. I tried to resolve these conflicts using the mergetool

   I had issues with git losing the conflict resolution with these files since the result of the diff is I always accept the local version that is correct, which git sees no change in.
5. I tried git `rebase --skip`
   but this did not seem helpful for the above, so I aborted
6. I tried to power through the merge but gave up after an hour. There are hundreds of commits that I made locally.
7. I turned on `rerere.enabled`, and tried the above again. rebase attempts to apply the `"recorded preimage"` but fails and I am asked to merge the non conflicts manually as before.

### Things that did work

I can merge into my branch without any problems. The merges are clean and automatic as they should be in this context. This was working quite well for me but I eventually have to push back and cannot propagate this issue.

### other information

I merged my branch back into the master, and now I find that doing a git pull --rebase to the master now has

```
    git checkout mybranch
    git merge master mybranch (success)
    git checkout master
    git merge mybranch master (success)
    git pull --rebase (conflicts in files that dont exist on remote.)
```

#### looks something like:

```
    master ----o-o-o-o--------o-o-------------o-------------------------------------------------------
                \          \ (pull --rebase)   \(pull --rebase (clean)           merged back (clean)  \ rebase
    local master ---o-o      o-o-o-o            o------------------------------o-----------------------X (rebase unclean)
                       \            \ (rebase)   \ merge to mybranch (clean)  /
    mybranch           --------A-B   o-A-B-C      o-----A-B-C-o-...-o-------
                                         (clean, before it stopped working)
```

My inclination is to give up on this local clone of the repository and merge into a new repository with a filesystem 
diff however I would really like to understand what is happening and if possible maintain the commit history, but I cannot merge back to the remote, although I imagine it would work, as I believe that would risk propagating this issue (whatever it is).

Comment: If you review the `git log` of `mybranch`, does the history look the way you expect?
Specifically, do you see any duplicate commit messages?
Alternatively, if you do an interactive rebase (`git rebase -i master`), is the list of commits correct - ie does it display "A B C"?

Comment: regarding git log: so far as I can tell the history is correct. There are hundreds of commits from many users, so it is hard to be sure. I did a little filtering on my username but nothing obviously wrong came up.
The interactive rebase when I looked before seemed reasonable as well.
after I start a rebase it rewinds and patches some number of commits from to target onto the source branch it starts into problems.

Comment: after a closer look I see that the first ~20 commits in the interactive rebase repeat, I am not sure what this means or how it relates to the problem if it does.

Answer (score 5):

Based on your comment "[...]the first ~20 commits in the interactive rebase repeat[...]", I believe I can explain the problem.

Suppose the commits are listed like this:

```
A
B
C
A
B
C
```

When Git performs the rebase, it attempts to apply each commit one-at-a-time in the order listed.

1. Apply commit `A` - No issues
2. Apply commit `B` - No issues
3. Apply commit `C` - No issues
4. Apply commit `A` - CONFLICT because these changes have already been applied

Of course, when you manually go to resolve the conflict nothing shows up because the change are identical. This is also why `merge` works without any problems - it is only comparing the latest versions.

---

**So, how do you fix this?**

1. `git rebase -i master`
2. Remove duplicate commit messages. This is tedious, but will only be necessary once
3. `git push -f`

---

**But how did this happen?**

This is pure speculation, but is how I got into a similar situation. At some point these commits were part of a branch structure similar to this:

```
master o-o-o-o-o
            \
branch-1     o-A-B-o
                    \
branch-2             o-o
```

Then `branch-1` was updated via `git rebase master`:

```
master o-o-o-o-o
            \   \
branch-1     \   o-A`-B`-o
              \
branch-2       o-A-B-o-o
```

Then `branch-2` was updated via `git rebase branch-1`:

```
master o-o-o-o-o
                \
branch-1         o-A`-B`-o
                          \
branch-2                   o-A-B-o-o
```

And thus the commits became duplicated.

---

**What next?**

If the duplicated commit messages are commits from `master` - someone else has re-written the history of `master`. This is bad form for anyone in a shared repo, and (if possible) you should change the permissions of `master` to disallow anyone to force push on it.

If the duplicated commit messages are from `mybranch`, then I'm guessing you had a child-branch at some point and made a mistake when getting the latest changes from master. I use the process described in [this article](https://coderwall.com/p/xzsr9g/rebasing-dependent-branches-with-git) to handle this situation (in short, you need to use the `--onto` flag when rebasing `branch-2`).

Comment: I appreciate the response. I feel your explanation for how it might have happened is very plausible.

question: "Remove duplicate commit messages. This is tedious, but will only be necessary once"

Does it matter if the first twenty or second twenty are removed? I am imagining they are all the same however there is a numerical tag on each line and the key(?) is different.

Regarding  "If the duplicated commit messages are commits from master - someone else has re-written the history of master."

Luckily the repeated rebase patches I see are all my commits, so master appears to be sane.

Comment: @btonner If you don't mind having the merge commits in the history and you're comfortable merging all your changes at once, then using merge is a viable option. Ultimately, it's whatever works best for you / your team / the repo owner.

Comment: Update: Removing the duplicate commits seems to have resolved the issue. Much appreciated.